# Can I create two canvas spaces in a unique html page?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I am trying to create an HTML page which has two canvas spaces, i. e. two rectangles where objects can be displayed.

In my HTML code I have this line, that represents a rectangle of dimensions 540x600 dp on the left side of the page:
`<canvas id="canvas" width="540" height="600"></canvas>`

But apart from that, I want to generate another canvas space on the right side. Is it possible? How could I do it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlow! Please make sure that you are aware about the [rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28679/the-rules-of-stack-overflow). If you find any of the answers good enough, please upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define as many canvas elements you want in a page. Just give them an unique ID and create a context for each one of them:

```
<canvas id="canvas1" width="540" height="600"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="540" height="600"></canvas>
```

They will be placed default as `inline`.

Then in your JavaScript code:

```
var ctx1 = document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d");
var ctx2 = document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d");
```

## Example

```js
var ctx1 = document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d");
var ctx2 = document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d");

ctx1.fillText("CANVAS 1", 10, 10);
ctx2.fillText("CANVAS 2", 10, 10);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" width="240" height="300"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="240" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Not sure if you really need that CSS. It is displayed inline anyway. :) Checkout the example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can! Just create another canvas element, plot data in to it and float it to the right through css.

Comment: You dont *have* to float it to the right. It will be displayed on the right anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`<canvas>` is displayed `inline` by default. So you dont have to worry about getting them to display side-by-side. Just give them unique ID's.

Checkout this example below in Full Page mode.

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas1" width="300" height="300" style="background: #0000FF;">
</canvas>

<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="300" height="300" style="background: #FF0000;">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no limits on how many canvasses/canvasi/canvi(?) you can draw on a page.

if you have your canvas like this:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="540" height="600"></canvas>
```

you can just add another one underneath it:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="540" height="600"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="540" height="600"></canvas>
```

If you want it to pull to the right, add a `float:right` in css (for example reasons, I did it inline here)

When you go to your javascript, just make sure to specify which canvas you want to draw on:

```
 var the_first_awesome_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
 var the_second_awesome_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas2');
```

And then specify the context for both:

```
 var context_for_first = the_first_awesome_canvas.getContext("2d");
 var context_for_second = the_second_awesome_canvas.getContext("2d");
```

And start drawing:

```
context_for_first.fillRect(0,0,50,50);
context_for_second.fillRect(0,0,50,50);
```